# Gradle how to include files conditionally?

Tags: if-statement, gradle, include

Gradle: how to include different files conditionally?

For example,

```
file1.js
file2.js

file3.js
file4.js

from (zipTree("/foo/bar.jar")) {
   include {
       if (project.hasProperty("debug"))
          //file1.js, file2.js
       else
          //file3.js, file4.js
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example like

```
from(zipTree('/foo/bar.jar')) {
    if (project.hasProperty('debug'))
        include 'file1.js', 'file2.js'
    else
        include 'file3.js', 'file4.js'
}
```

or like

```
from(zipTree('/foo/bar.jar')) {
    include project.hasProperty('debug') ? ['file1.js', 'file2.js'] : ['file3.js', 'file4.js']
}
```